# Accessing and extending JS prototype in jquery scope for use in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a third party API that is using jquery and JavaScript.  Inside the `$(function() {` scope there are several prototypes defined.  For example, say this is 'Note.js':

```
$(function() {
"use strict";

var $doc = $(document);
var queryParams = window.ControlUtils.getQueryStringMap();
if (queryParams.getBoolean('hideAnnotationPanel', false)) {
    return;
}

var Note = function(annotation, editable, replyable, deletable) {
    this._editable = editable;
    this._replyable = replyable;
    this._deletable = deletable;
    this._isEditing = false;
    this._stayUncollapsed = false;
    this._annotation = annotation;
    this._parent = null;

    this.$container = $('<div class="noteContainer">');

    this.createContainer();
};

Note.prototype = {
    COLLAPSE_HEIGHT: 120,

    createContainer: function() {
        var me = this;
        var annotation = this.getAnnotation();
        var $container = this.getContainer();
        $container.data('annot', annotation);
        // Continue on...
},
    isEditing: function() {
        return this._isEditing;
    },

    forceUncollapsed: function() {
        this._stayUncollapsed = true;
    },

    unforceUncollapsed: function() {
        this._stayUncollapsed = false;
    }

    // Continue on...
};

$.extend(Note.prototype, window.utils.eventHandler);

What I would like to do, is take all those prototypes and move them to TypeScript Interfaces/Classes so I can extend them and get all the benefits of TS with a clear 'cut' to the 3rd party API.
```

I've gone through some tutorials and SO questions on some ways to do this, but I can't seem to even reference the prototype in my *.ts file.

What is the best way to do this?

My end goal is to have a 'FooNote.ts' file with a class like:

```
class FooNote extends Note {
    // ...
}
```

Using something like (not sure if correct):

```
interface Note {
    foo(): Note
}

Note.prototype.foo = function(): Note {
    // return some Note here.
}
```

Comment: You can create definitions for the `Note` type, it should be a `class` not an interface. But what I am unsure, is if the `Note` class is accessible from the outside. How would you use `Note` in plain JS ?

Comment: I have no idea about that either.  I'm both a jquery and js newbie (C#, C++ background).  Sitting here right now reading some documentation on jquery.  It seems like this has to be a solved problem, though.  I can't be the only one wanting something like this.

Comment: Is this API internal or publicly available ? If public what is it, maybe I can have a look. If this is created as a JQuery plugin, `Note` may not be accessible from anywhere except that function, and it may only be used in the plugin.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough code. It's unclear what happens with `Note` then. If it isn't exposed somehow, it isn't possible to reach local scope from the outside.

Comment: So, basically, some other prototype/class must expose the 'Note.prototype' so that I can extend it, and that's an API problem not a language problem if it's not exposed somehow?  I'll agree to that.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Seems to only be used in that one file.  I can't find where it's exposed.  I'm used to being able to extend a type/class in other languages unless it's explicitly sealed off...which this seems to be.  Also, this is not a public API.